# Pattern Matching Case Classes with Common Trait

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, traits, case-class

I am writing some code that uses pattern matching. In testing I found a strange result:

```
object Example extends App {

  trait Human {
    def sing(): Unit
  }

  case class Son(name: String) extends Human {
    override def sing(): Unit = println("son " + name)
  }

  case class Daughter(name: String) extends Human {
    override def sing(): Unit = println("daughter " + name)
  }
  
  val jack = Son("jack")
  val sonia = Daughter("sonia")

  def f1(lst: List[Human]) = {
    lst match {
      case a: List[Son] => println("human is son")
      case b: List[Daughter] => println("human is daughter")
    }
  }

  f1(List(jack))
  f1(List(sonia))
}
```

Both these print "human is a son". Is there a way around this? I can see the compiler matches both Son and Daughter to Human. But is there a way to get it to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Due type erasure you can not check if `lst` is a `List[Son]` or `List[Daughter]` you can only check if it is a list _(which you already know, so it is useless)_. What do you really want to do? There may be workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I am basically refactoring some existing code to get rid of redundancies. One of the functions basically takes in a List[Human]. I wanted to somehow pattern match into two code paths; one for Son and one for Daughter. But I will see if I can try another way - seems erasure will not allow me to do so.

Comment: There is a nice post about it. https://gist.github.com/jkpl/5279ee05cca8cc1ec452fc26ace5b68b#avoid-matching-on-generic-type-parameters

Comment: @finite_diffidence if you wantm edit the question _(or open a new one)_ with more details about the underlying problem and we may be able to propose alternatives.

Comment: Thanks I will open a new one, although I think I managed to refactor the code as per your advice by removing a list. Thanks for the feedback, sometimes just talking to someone can fix the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you really need to refactor your design. You shouldn't need to check the type elements in a list at runtime - you can have an overridden method if you want dynamic dispatch, or you can use separate methods for `List[Son]`s and `List[Daughter]`.

If you *really* want to make sure that all of the elements of the list are sons/daughters, you can use `forall`

```
def f1(lst: List[Human]) =
    if (lst.forall(_.isInstanceOf[Son])) println("human is son")
    else if (lst.forall(_.isInstanceOf[Daughter])) println("human is daughter")
```

This isn't great, though. What if there's a list with Sons *and* Daughters, or maybe some third type altogether?

I'd recommend 2 different methods - one for `Son`s and one for `Daughter`s. I would also make your `Human` trait sealed so no new implementations have to be dealt with.

```
def f1(lst: List[Daughter]) = println("human is daughter")
//DummyImplicit is a workaround for type erasure, otherwise, they'd have the same signature
def f1(lst: List[Son])(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = println("human is son")
```

You could also use typeclasses, although it doesn't seem worth it here

```
def f1[A <: Human](lst: List[A])(implicit idr: Identifier[A]) =
  idr.identify(lst)

sealed trait Identifier[A <: Human] {
  def identify(lst: List[A]): String
}
object Identifier {
  implicit val sonIdentifier: Identifier[Son] = _ => "human is son"
  implicit val daughterIdentifier: Identifier[Daughter] = _ => "human is daughter"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Refactored code to get rid of List[Human] fixed the issue.

Instead of operating on a list, it was observed that we could simply extract the first element of the list in this specific scenario.